# cannot make list item visible with > CSS selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm unable to make the popups 'redItem', 'blueItem' and 'greenItem' below visible again after setting their display to 'none'.  I'm using a CSS selector to get them visible again when the mouse hovers over a node higher up in the nested list to no avail.

Here's the code:

```
<ul class="popups" style="vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
 <li style="width: 165px"><a id="topmostBox" href="#">One_high-up_item</a>
  <ul class="popups">
   <li><a href="#">First-lower-item</a>
    <ul class="popups">
     <li name="redItem" ><a href="#" onclick="setTopColorAndVis(this)">Red</a></li>
     <li name="blueItem"><a href="#" onclick="setTopColorAndVis(this)">Blue</a></li>
     <li name="greenItem"><a href="#" onclick="setTopColorAndVis(this)">Green</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

 .popups:hover > li {
         display: block;
  }

 .popups {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;        
    font-size: 13.5px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-width: .05em;
    border-top-color: rgb(165,165,165);
    line-height: 1.2em;
    display: inline-table;
 }

 function setTopColorAndVis(theNestedPopupAnchor)
 {
    var theColorName = theNestedPopupAnchor.innerHTML;   
    var topMenuBox = document.getElementById('topmostBox');

    topMenuBox.innerHTML = theColorName ;
    theNestedPopupAnchor.parentNode.style.display = "none";
 }
```

What happens is this:

1) I select the color 'Red' (the 1st list item)

2)  my call to  setTopColorAndVis(this) makes the popup disappear (because the user selected an item, the color "Red", and now the popup is not needed for now)

3) but when I later hover the mouse over the "First-lower-item"  list item, the child li that has the ul containing 'redItem', 'greenItem', 'blueItem' does *not* appear.

So my experience here is that I'm successfully able to hide the list items named 'redItem', 'blueItem' and 'greenItem' -- but when I **hover** over the "First-lower-item", despite my CSS code:

```
 .popups:hover > li {
display: block;
  }
```

The 'redItem', 'greenItem' and 'blueItem'  do NOT reappear.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I believe you're hiding the parent of the item. So you displaying the child item won't really display anything as the parent is hidden. I'm not sure this is correct but it seems that way

Comment: Please provide more of your code or a live example so we can help you more

Comment: @ZachSaucier, this isn't deployed yet, I have to get the above to work before it goes live.  The code above is extracted from a page, but that's all there is to it for now, just a very simple page with the above popups, just trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline style overrides you style in your css code. you should use `onmouseover` event  and `onmouseout` instead.

Try

```
    <li name="redItem" ><a href="#" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)" onclick="setTopColorAndVis(this)">Red</a></li>


function show(elem){
  elem.parentNode.style.display = "block";
}

function hide(elem){
  elem.parentNode.style.display = "none";
```

}

Comment: By 'inline style' do you mean that by programmtically (in my code) setting the display to none, that makes display:none an inline style?  I did not know that; I *did* know that inline styles override the CSS class.   Do you mean that when my code set the display to 'none' that the 'none' became the inline style for that item?

Comment: Yes they do, thats why they are called 'Cascading Style Sheets'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `:hover` over an element with `display:none` as it has no size...
instead of working with `display`, you can work with `visibility` - which will leave an area to hover over.

like so:

```
theNestedPopupAnchor.parentNode.style.visibility = 'hidden'

.popups:hover > li {
     visibility: visible;
 }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: [W3Fools](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3fools.com%2F&ei=Ay-3Uo_5ApTnkAfQwIC4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFCfHZjqL1TEK6qfbpZegOfzTQLIw&sig2=I-pOI3h7TwVmw7-13vYX-g), I'd recommend using another source